# Negative epoch values failing to get parsed using strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second (Opensearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am using this version of opensearch:

```
  "version": {
    "distribution": "opensearch",
    "number": "1.3.11",
    "build_type": "rpm",
    "build_hash": "d104ed30b8c30d4e3313c30882ca8563feef5775",
    "build_date": "2023-06-23T18:09:44.285311Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "8.10.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
```

I have the following mapping:

```
"properties": {
    "DATE_CREATED": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second"
    }
  }
```

When I try to insert the following value into this index:

```
"DATE_CREATED": -2177434800
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "failed to parse field [DATE_CREATED] of type [date] in document with id '2128'. Preview of field's value: '-2177434800'"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse field [DATE_CREATED] of type [date] in document with id '2128'. Preview of field's value: '-2177434800'",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "date_time_exception",
            "reason": "Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): -2177434800"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

It looks like `-2177434800` (Tuesday, 1 January 1901 05:00:00) is being converted using the `strict_date_optional_time` (and failing) rather than the `epoch_second` convertor.

I can fix this by changing the mapping from:

`"format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second"`

to

`"format": "epoch_second||strict_date_optional_time"`

however this would require me to create a new index and re-index all my docs.

I think this is a bug as `-2177434800` should not be trying to be converted using the `strict_date_optional_time` convertor, or if it fails, then the `epoch_second` convertor should be used?

I am also seeing slightly different errors with other date values such as `-377476136`:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "failed to parse field [DATE_CREATED] of type [date] in document with id '2128'. Preview of field's value: '-377476136'"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse field [DATE_CREATED] of type [date] in document with id '2128'. Preview of field's value: '-377476136'",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "arithmetic_exception",
            "reason": "long overflow"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this still happens on OS 2.9 and 2.11, but not on the latest ES 8.10.4 release and [this probably explains the origin of the issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/51080#issuecomment-575621777)